# List of localized month/day names

Tags: php, time, localization

Actually I'm using this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');

$monthNames = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    $monthNames[] = strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i));
}
```

Is there a simpler and nicer way to do this? Furthermore this doesn't work well with the names of the days. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$daysOfWeek = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', ...);
foreach ($daysOfWeek as $day) {
    echo strftime('%A', strtotime("last $day")), "\n";
}
```

This is one way to do it, I suppose.  I didn't see any built-in functions for grabbing localized days of the week or months.

Answer (score 1):

Php provide few handy [Calendar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.calendar.php) related functions, like [`call_info`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-info.php):

```
$info = cal_info(0);
print_r($info);
```

Comment: Thank you but unluckily this doesn't provide the names of the days of the week. :( I think I'll just use my code plus the one provide by the other answer!